# Mysql query - using Locate function in case statement to group traffic by source

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case

I'm basically trying to group my traffic based on the traffic source

Lets say the table has the following columns

```
Enrollment_ID |      last_modified         | referrer
     1        |   2012-07-01 15:00:00      | http://www.facebook.com/l.php?xyz
     2        |   2012-07-01 16:00:00      | http://www.facebook.com/l.php?abc
```

Now the referrer is different - so even if I group it by referrer - it wont say 2
So this is the query I used

```
select count(*) as 'Enrollments',date_format(e.last_modified,'%d/%m/%y') as 'Date', if(LOCATE('facebook', referrer)>0,'facebook',referrer) as 'referrer'
from enrollment e
where e.last_modified >='2012-07-01 00:00:00'
group by date_format(e.last_modified,'%d/%m/%y'),3
```

This works fine. But obviously I'm going to have more than one referrer.
So I thought of using case statement

```
select count(*) as 'Enrollments',date_format(e.last_modified,'%d/%m/%y') as 'Date', 
case referrer
when LOCATE('facebook', referrer)>0 then 'facebook' 
when LOCATE('google', referrer)>0 then 'google' 
else referrer
end as 'referrer'
from enrollment e
where e.last_modified >='2012-07-01 00:00:00'
group by date_format(e.last_modified,'%d/%m/%y'),3
```

This does not work as expected.

For the first and second query - I have created a sql fiddle

First - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70f6b/2

Second - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad890/3

I'll appreciate if someone can take a quick glance at it

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I never use MySQL, but I'm used to there being two types of CASE statements in other databases and you seem to be trying to mix them.

A

```
CASE <Field Name>
WHEN <value>...
```

B

```
CASE
WHEN <condition>...
```

So, just delete your first reference to referrer, and your query may work:

```
case
  when LOCATE('facebook', referrer)>0 then 'facebook' 
  when LOCATE('google', referrer)>0 then 'google' 
else referrer
end as 'referrer'
```

Another thing is that it might be cleaner to try to split referrer into several fields, where one of them was the internet address.

Comment: oops - thanks a lot - that worked :) - appreciate you looking into it